# NumberFormat to Number in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, currency

I really want to know how to make the inverse process of this

```
fun makeAFormattedString(currencyCode: String, numberToConvert: Float): String{
    val format: NumberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()
    format.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    format.currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode)
    return format.format(numberToConvert)
}
```

when I type: ("MXN",3000) my result is

*"MX $3000.00"*

I want to know how to get the number (**3000**) with this string

**"MX $3000.00"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"MX $3000.00".takeLastWhile { it != '$' }
```

is one of many ways.

```
val result = "[^\\d]+?(\\d+\\.?\\d*)".toRegex().find("MX $3000.00")
result?.groupValues?.last()
```

works too.

The problem is there's no way to tell whether you started with an `Int` or a `Float`. If you started with `3000`, it formats as `3000.00` and if you started with `3000.45`, it formats as `3000.45`. The result will be a `Float`, and you can choose what to do with it.

Comment: Thank you so much... The second one works like a charm ;)

Comment: @AntonioLabra Both work, choose whichever one you prefer.